# Simple extension of a simple extension

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

Let $E / F$ be a field extension, and let $\alpha, \beta \in E$. Is it true in general that $\left(F(\alpha)\right)(\beta) = F(\alpha, \beta)$? (I.e., that $F'(\beta) = F(\alpha, \beta)$ where $F' = F(\alpha)$.)

I haven't been able to find a counterexample.

Comment: yes it's always true.

Comment: I would even say it is more or less the definition.